# Android Twitter login error

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I have integrated twitter in my android application. It worked fine for long time, but now it giving error while i am trying to lo-gin to twitter. It giving the following error:"Failed to get request token" and the stack trace are below. please help me to resolve this issue.

```
    02-20 19:44:09.687: D/TwitterApp(3928): Failed to get request token
02-20 19:44:09.687: W/System.err(3928): oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: Service provider responded in error: 301 (Moved Permanently)
02-20 19:44:09.687: W/System.err(3928):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:214)
02-20 19:44:09.687: W/System.err(3928):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:69)
02-20 19:44:09.687: W/System.err(3928):     at com.twitter.android.TwitterApp$2.run(TwitterApp.java:108)
02-20 19:44:09.687: W/System.err(3928): Caused by: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Service provider responded in error: 301 (Moved Permanently)
02-20 19:44:09.687: W/System.err(3928):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.handleUnexpectedResponse(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:241)
02-20 19:44:09.687: W/System.err(3928):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:189)
02-20 19:44:09.687: W/System.err(3928):     ... 2 more
```

Thanks
Murali

Comment: does this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933160/service-provider-responded-in-error-301-moved-permanently-twitter-api

Comment: Welcome always first try to find similar question asked on stackoverflow..

Answer (score 1):

Try to make a secure request. Instead of http://twitter.com, use always https://twitter.com. It worked for me. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This post also helps you in urls to be used while calling constructor stackoverflow.com/questions/14933160/…

you may suffer with this problem if you didn't add Callback Url: to Application Type in your application's Settings tab when you create application at dev.twitter.com.

This fix works for me. Hope works for others come across same problem.