# Authorization error with jTwitter for android

Tags: android, twitter, signpost, jtwitter

I am using jTwitter library in my android application. Till day before yesterday everything was working fine. But today am getting exception "Service provider responded in error : 301". Kindly help me.

Here is ther stack trace :

```
02-21 21:07:27.258: E/AndroidRuntime(4013): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-21 21:07:27.258: E/AndroidRuntime(4013): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-21 21:07:27.258: E/AndroidRuntime(4013):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
02-21 21:07:27.258: E/AndroidRuntime(4013):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
02-21 21:07:27.258: E/AndroidRuntime(4013):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
02-21 21:07:27.258: E/AndroidRuntime(4013):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
02-21 21:07:27.258: E/AndroidRuntime(4013):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-21 21:07:27.258: E/AndroidRuntime(4013):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-21 21:07:27.258: E/AndroidRuntime(4013):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
02-21 21:07:27.258: E/AndroidRuntime(4013):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
02-21 21:07:27.258: E/AndroidRuntime(4013):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-21 21:07:27.258: E/AndroidRuntime(4013): Caused by: winterwell.jtwitter.TwitterException: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: Service provider responded in error: 301 (Moved Permanently)
02-21 21:07:27.258: E/AndroidRuntime(4013):     at winterwell.jtwitter.OAuthSignpostClient.authorizeUrl(OAuthSignpostClient.java:307)
02-21 21:07:27.258: E/AndroidRuntime(4013):     at com.example.retrieve.contacts.twitter.MainActivity$MyTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:363)
02-21 21:07:27.258: E/AndroidRuntime(4013):     at com.example.retrieve.contacts.twitter.MainActivity$MyTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
02-21 21:07:27.258: E/AndroidRuntime(4013):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-21 21:07:27.258: E/AndroidRuntime(4013):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
02-21 21:07:27.258: E/AndroidRuntime(4013):     ... 5 more
02-21 21:07:27.258: E/AndroidRuntime(4013): Caused by: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: Service provider responded in error: 301 (Moved Permanently)
02-21 21:07:27.258: E/AndroidRuntime(4013):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:214)
02-21 21:07:27.258: E/AndroidRuntime(4013):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:69)
02-21 21:07:27.258: E/AndroidRuntime(4013):     at winterwell.jtwitter.OAuthSignpostClient.authorizeUrl(OAuthSignpostClient.java:303)
02-21 21:07:27.258: E/AndroidRuntime(4013):     ... 9 more
02-21 21:07:27.258: E/AndroidRuntime(4013): Caused by: oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Service provider responded in error: 301 (Moved Permanently)
02-21 21:07:27.258: E/AndroidRuntime(4013):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.handleUnexpectedResponse(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:241)
02-21 21:07:27.258: E/AndroidRuntime(4013):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:189)
```

Comment: I just found this by searching for the problem. It seems more than a couple people are having it right now.

Comment: yeah seems like it. People using twitter4j are also having the same problem.

Comment: You can see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933160/service-provider-responded-in-error-301-moved-permanently-twitter-api-1-1

Comment: @user527759 could you please elaborate. In my application i havent specified any urls for request_token, access_token, etc... I am using jTwitter library. In jTwitter everything is built in i guess. What do i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter changed their API. It's a trivial but annoying change to the oauth url.

This is fixed in the latest version of JTwitter (2.7) -- which you can download from the [JTwitter webpage](http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter.php)