# Twitter not get post -- android

Tags: android, twitter

I am sharing my string and images via twitter using twitte SDK. The code which i used to transfer my content to twitter works fine previously, but now i am getting OAuthCommunication Exception.

```
oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: Service provider responded in error: 301 (Moved Permanently)
```

Can anyone guide me how to solve this issue.

Comment: Check this pls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933160/service-provider-responded-in-error-301-moved-permanently-twitter-api-1-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Twitter Oauth paths with https:

```
new DefaultOAuthProvider("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
                        "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
                        "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize");
```

[Courtesy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933160/service-provider-responded-in-error-301-moved-permanently-twitter-api-1-1)